# Django 2 url path matching negative value

Tags: python, django, django-urls

In Django <2 the normal way of doing this is to use regex expression. But it is now recommended in Django => 2 to use path() instead of url()

```
path('account/<int:code>/', views.account_code, name='account-code')
```

This looks okay and works well matching url pattern

```
/account/23/
/account/3000/
```

However, this issue is that I also want this to match negative integer like

```
/account/-23/
```

Please how do I do this using path()?

Comment: Have you tried to URL encode your URL? [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410993/django-problem-of-resolving-special-characters-in-url)

Comment: Submitted a bug report for this - https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/29143. CC @neverwalkaloner

Comment: Apparently, this is an [intended behavior](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#path-converters) "Matches zero or any positive integer. Returns an int."

Comment: By definition integer value includes negative values too. I don't know why this should assure an absolute integer behaviour

Answer (score 29):

You can write [custom](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/#registering-custom-path-converters) path converter:

```
class NegativeIntConverter:
    regex = '-?\d+'

    def to_python(self, value):
        return int(value)

    def to_url(self, value):
        return '%d' % value
```

In urls.py:

```
from django.urls import register_converter, path

from . import converters, views

register_converter(converters.NegativeIntConverter, 'negint')

urlpatterns = [
    path('account/<negint:code>/', views.account_code),
    ...
]
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm too lazy to make a fancy path converter, so I just captured it as a string and cast it to an integer in the view (with some basic sanity checking to make sure the value can be properly cast to an integer):

## urls.py

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('account/<str:code>/', views.account_code),
    ...
]
```

## views.py (new)

Function-Based View (FBV) example:

```py
from django.http import HttpResponseNotFound

def your_view(request, code):
    try:
        code = int(self.kwargs['code'])  # cast to integer
    except ValueError:
        return HttpResponseNotFound(
            "'code' must be convertible to an integer.")
```

Class-Based View (CBV) example:

```py
from django.http import HttpResponseNotFound
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

class CodeView(TemplateView):

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            code = int(self.kwargs['code'])  # cast to integer
        except ValueError:
            return HttpResponseNotFound(
                "'code' must be convertible to an integer.")
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

If you wanted the user to know that a client-side error occurred, you could substitute `HttpResponseNotFound` with `HttpResponseBadRequest`, which would give an HTTP status code 400 (Bad Request)

---

EDIT: The version below produces a server error HTTP response code and is probably not desirable (may show up in error logs, etc.)

## views.py (old, left here for historical reasons)

```py
try:
    code = int(self.kwargs['code'])  # cast to integer
except ValueError:
    raise ValueError("'code' must be convertible to an integer.")
```

Comment: Simple and effective!

Comment: This is how I had a view set up, until it conflicted with a URL with a string afterwards. Think something like:  /foo/<str:bar_id>/, /foo/bar/

Comment: Good point @JosiahDub. I guess you'd have to make sure the URL with the custom string came afterwards... or just use the path converter suggested by the other answer.